# What is a good strategy for catching horses?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

What are some good methods of catching horses in Breath of the Wild?

I've found using apples to bait them towards me while hiding in bushes to work well, but sneaking up behind them takes a considerable amount of time. Are there any other effective methods?

Comment: Try landing on them from above using the glider.

Comment: Put one into a stable and just take it out from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1: Stealth**

According to [this guide](https://www.polygon.com/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-guide-walkthrough/2017/3/9/14871698/white-giant-horse-best-customize-bridal-saddle-reigns-royal-tame-save-stats-sidestep-kill), one strategy is to simply try to sneak up on the horses, and try to catch them in this way. If the horse is special in some way (eg the [Giant Horse](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Giant_Horse)), using a meal or an elixir that temporarily helps improve stealth may help to capture the horse (eg see the Sneaky Elixir [here](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Elixirs)). As you mentioned in your question [apples](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Apple) can also be used to help woo horses, though some stealth may still be required.

You mentioned in your question this method can take a lot of time. I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwCwv78rHy8) showing how to use this method quickly - you'll note that the person actually fails catching a horse on his first try. This is OK, just keep trying and it will eventually work. Also try to approach from behind - this will ensure the horses don't notice you, and maximize your chances of catching one. You can also try using some [armour](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Armor) that boosts your stealth.

**Method 2: Bokoblins**

Another method [described here](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/How_to_Tame_a_Horse) for catching a horse is to steal one from a mounted [Bokoblin](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Bokoblin#Breath_of_the_Wild). While these horses may not have maximum bond with Link, they will be fairly easy to tame. Simply knock a Bokoblin off of its horse, and mount the horse to catch it.

**Method 3: Paragliding**

Finally, in my experience, you can also try to use your paraglider to drop on them from above. I found this to be a bit tricky to do (since you have to land perfectly on the horse), however if you are having problems with sneaking this method could work, since the horses tend not to notice when you're landing on them from above. Importantly, this method has one drawback: it robs you of your stamina, which you need to tame the horse. Since paragliding uses up stamina, and taming a horse also requires stamina, this method may not be feasible if you haven't already upgraded your stamina.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZgodGvbt2M) shows the general paragliding strategy, though as you can see, landing it correctly can be difficult.

Comment: It should be noted that Bokoblin horses always have only 2 stamina, at least in my experience. Useful if you need quick access to faster move speeds, but not worth boarding, IMO.

Comment: @MageXy I would totally agree, though decided to gloss over the details of pros/cons of specific horses since the question was about the methodology of catching horses, and not the quality of the horses being caught

Answer (score 1):

I usually get them by sneaking up behind them and BARELY MOVING when I am crouched. Also, stealth dishes or clothes could help.

Answer (score -1):

Wait for the rain and then sneak up on them. Also I don't know if you have Rivali's Gale yet but I usually just do that and then paraglide down and land right on top of them. There are probably a few locations where you can climb up high and then paraglide down onto them without the gale.

Comment: This doesn't add anything new. Sneaking and paragliding have already been mentioned in the accepted